# Какие реализации паттерна проектирования "Декоратор" вы знаете?

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Хотелось бы узнать о том, как данный паттерн может быть реализован, но не по "стандартной" схеме, предложенной GOF.
Привожу пример "стандартной" реализации.

```
class Component
{ Component() { ... } }
class ConcreteComponent : Component
{ ConcreteComponent() { ... } }
class Decorator : Component
{ 
    Component c; 
    int newState; 
    public void SetComponent(Component component) { ... }
    Decorator() { ... } 
}
```

Можно ли декорировать объекты как-то по другому, не совмещая агрегацию и наследование, но чтобы при этом сохранялись все преимущества паттерна? Желательно на C#.

Comment: В книге [Patterns of parallel programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) by Stephen Toub (по ссылке можно официально скачать бесплатно) в разделе Decorator to pipilene (стр. 56) приведен пример реализации декоратора для потоков (stream), позволяющий распараллеливать интенсивные вычисления, например, шифрование и сжатие. И вообще книга кладезь полезных приемов.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я обычно использую декораторы вместе с интерфейсом и композицией.

Например, есть некоторый источник данных о погоде:

```
public interface IWeatherProvider
{
    public WeatherInfo GetWeather(string city);
}
```

Есть реализация по умолчанию. Например, она ходит по http к провайдеру данных:

```
public class DefaultWeatherProvider : IWeatherProvider
{
    public WeatherInfo GetWeather(string city)
    {
        // обращение по HTTP
    }
}
```

В некоторых сценариях нам необязательно запрашивать погоду каждый раз у провайдера, а достаточно кэшировать ее:

```
public class CachingWeatherProvider : IWeatherProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, WeatherInfo> _cache;
    private readonly IWeatherProvider _provider;

    public CachingWeatherProvider(IWeatherProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _cache = new Dictionary<string, WeatherInfo>();
    }

    public WeatherInfo GetWeather(string city)
    {
        WeatherInfo weather;
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(city, out weather))
        {
            weather = _provider.GetWeather(city);
            _cache[city] = weather;
        }
        return weather;
    }
}
```

Используем:

```
var provider = new CachingWeatherProvider(new DefaultWeatherProvider());
```

Или вдруг источник ненадежный, часто лежит, и вы захотели добавить ретрай:

```
public class RetryingWeatherProvider : IWeatherProvider
{
    private readonly IWeatherProvider _provider;
    private int _maxRetries;

    public RetryingWeatherProvider(IWeatherProvider provider, int maxRetries)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _maxRetries = maxRetries;
    }

    public WeatherInfo GetWeather(string city)
    {
        int retry = 0;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                return _provider.GetWeather(city);
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                if (retry == _maxRetries)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                else
                {
                    // подождем немного
                }
            }
        }
        while (++retry < _maxRetries)
    }
}
```

И тогда можно наворотить провайдер с кэшем и ретраем:

```
var provider = new CachingWeatherProvider(
    new RetryingWeatherProvider(new DefaultWeatherProvider(), 3));
```

Как именно реализуется декоратор в принципе неважно, отличия имеют право на жизнь. Важно лишь помнить про [open-closed принцип](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.co.at/2014/08/open-closed-principle.html): декоратор очень полезен, когда вам нужно расширить функциональность кода, не трогая при этом основной код. У вас есть провайдер данных. Чтобы добавить функциональность ретрая, вы не лезете в основной провайдер, а создаете декоратор. Чтобы добавить кэширование, вы опять же не лезете в провайдер, а создаете еще один декоратор и т.д.

P.S. Весь приведенный код не production ready, а только иллюстрация.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный пример. Жаль не могу плюсовать! 
Тут опять же есть реализация интерфейса и есть композиция :) Понравилось, как Вы создаете объект в конце.
 Вопрос был вызван реакцией на мой предыдущий вопрос про "поиск паттернов в исходном коде", реакция была такова, что дескать паттерны можно реализовать по-разному, поэтому найти в коде их не получится. Вот я и пытаюсь придумать "нестандартные" реализации паттернов проектирования

Comment: @PashaKrizskiy однозначно найти в коде действительно не получится, т.к. паттерны в чистом виде мало применимы к реальным задачам. Они описывают способы решения некоторых проблем изолированно, тогда как в реальном коде у вас может использоваться несколько паттернов одновременно на довольно скромном участке кода. Примерно также как разделы теоретической физика, они несомненно описывают конкретные явления, но лишь с какой-то одной стороны, в то время как само описываемое явление неизмеримо сложнее.  **andreycha**, а пример правда классный, утащу в закладки.